# Showing $[X,Y]=[Y,X]$ for subgroups $X,Y\leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am doing some study in regard to commutators and commutator subgroups.

I have shown that $[x,y]\ne [y,x]$ in general, by looking at $D_3$(with this notation referring to dihedral group on a 3-gon). Now I am told that $[X,Y]=[Y,X]$ does hold when $X,Y$ are subgroups of some $G$. I haven't been able to prove this, since I find the definition of $[X,Y]$ somewhat confusing. Specifically since $[X,Y]$ is *generated* by $[x,y],\forall x\in X, y\in Y$, rather than just having these as elements.

What I would do if I understood what elements looked like (i.e. I had the sets described in set-builder notation), is let $a\in [X,Y]$, and look at the structure of $a$, then show that this is in $[Y,X]$. But here $a$ could look like (since $[X,Y]$ may not be abelian):

$$a=x_1y_1x_1^{-1}y_1^{-1}(x_cy_kx_c^{-1}y_k^{-1})^{-1}\cdots$$

And it gets confusing...

Comment: By symmetry, you need only show that one is included in the other. For this it is sufficient to show that the generators of one are in the other, i.e. show $[x,y]\in[Y,X]$ for all $x\in X,y\in Y$.

Comment: @Jason That's a great idea, I think I can do this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X, Y \le G$ and $x \in X$, $y \in Y$. Then

$$
[x, y]^{-1} = (x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}(x^{-1}y^{-1})^{-1} = y^{-1} x^{-1}yx = [y, x].
$$

Apply the inverse on both sides to obtain

$$
[x, y] = [y, x]^{-1}.
$$

Hence, if $a \in [X, Y]$, i. e.

$$
a = \prod_{j=1}^n [x_j, y_j]^{k_j},
$$

then

$$
a = \prod_{j=1}^n [y_j, x_j]^{-k_j} \in [Y, X].
$$

This shows that $[X, Y] \subseteq [Y, X]$, and a similar argument (the same but with $X$ and $Y$ exchanged) proves that $[Y, X] \subseteq [X, Y]$, hence $[X, Y] = [Y, X]$.

Comment: That's great, thank you!